Would Eldritch Blast using a Dexterity Save instead of Spell Attack be appropriate for a low-confidence player?
Often a DM may invite a friend who is not as familiar, nor confident, with the rules of the game, particularly all the special conditions that come with ranged-attacks (weapon or spell).  Other players at the table are very confident and familiar with the rules.
A Warlock has only four spells with ranged attack rolls, and Eldritch Blast could be a very dependable cantrip that scales well - if not for how the ranged attack has many idiosyncrasies that trip up novice players who are already lacking confidence in combat.
This is the original spell:

A beam of crackling energy streaks toward a creature within range.  Make a ranged spell attack against the target. On a hit, the target takes 1d10 force damage.
The spell creates more than one beam when you reach higher levels: two
beams at 5th level, three beams at 11th level, and four beams at 17th
level. You can direct the beams at the same target or at different
ones. Make a separate attack roll for each beam.

Here is my proposed change to help that player be included (adjusted parts in bold):

A beam of crackling energy streaks toward a creature you can see
within range. The target must succeed on a Dexterity saving throw or
take 1d10 force damage.
The spell creates more than one beam when you reach higher levels: two
beams at 5th level, three beams at 11th level, and four beams at 17th
level. You can direct the beams at the same target or at different
ones. The target or targets make a separate dexterity save for each beam.

This allows the novice player to have a much more seamless transition between the three stages of interaction in D&D as outlined page 181 of the PHB:


The DM describes the environment.
The players describe what they want to do.
The DM narrates the results of their actions.


The player can describe that they want to cast this unlimited-use spell and the DM can make the saving roll without having to prompt the low-confidence player of what to do, exactly which dice to roll, what numbers to add, and why. They're still rolling some dice, but have only one damage die to worry about.
The player wouldn't have to be "told how to play the game", be confused as to why they have to roll with disadvantage to hit a prone opponent, or worry about being adjacent to hostile creatures.
Further confusion for the player

This is a very specific concern, since if you depend on a ranged-attack to attack the enemy and a melee enemy closes to within 5ft, then having ranged attack vs melee attack is very ineffective (disadvantage on the attack) and if you instead use your action to retreat the enemy will obviously follow with as much movement speed and attack. So retreat with disengage again, and followed and attacked again. It's a death cycle.

The downsides would be no critical hits and no advantage as an unseen attacker.
But this would then be a cantrip that is save-based that has a much longer range. Would this spell need some nerfs to balance its capability or is this an adequate side-grade?
Would there be any particular problems from this cantrip being a Dexterity save; should it be some other save? I default to a dex-save as usually it's the stat most likely already known by a DM for targets since you need to know it for initiative. Also, as a Dex save Partial Cover is still a limitation on the spell similar to a Ranged Spell Attack.
Clarification
I'd like to remind everyone that ability checks are rolls commanded by the DM, players don't need to know to know when to roll. There is no such thing as "I make a Charisma (Deception) check on the guard, does a 22 hit - I mean - does a 22 trick him?" you describe your interaction and if an ability check is appropriate the DM will ask for it and say which ability it is.
And under the Skills with Different Abilities variant rule (PHB pg. 175) you don't even know what skill proficiency to add until the DM tells you. So everyone is in the same situation here of being prompted by the DM of when to roll and what to add to the roll.
This is not something where the novice player is at a particular detriment, unlike attack rolls in combat where they need to be executed in a particular way on their own volition and under time pressure.

Slightly less powerful, maybe less fun and more cumbersome
The average save fail rate for Dexterity, based on all the monsters in the Monster Manual and their Dexterity scores vs the expected spell save DC of the character is about 60%*. The average to hit rate with an attack roll, spell attack or otherwise is about 65%. So this would lower the hit rate by 5% (more if the caster has something like a wand of the war mage, which is in the core rules, while uncommon magic items that improve your spell save DC are not). On top of that is that you lose critical hits. Those happen in 5% of the attacks, doubling the damage. So this will deal an expected ~10% less damage, maybe even less depending on the PC's magic items.
In addition, players enjoy rolling attacks. For some weird psychological reason, it is more frustrating if an enemy saves vs your spell, negating the effect, than when you miss with an attack. It also is common that players roll attacks, while the DM rolls saving throws for the monsters, so they get to roll less, and you have more work. You could assign that job to the players, though.

* I got to these numbers based on tabulating all the monsters and their Dexterity bonuses in a spreadsheet, then comparing this against the expected characters primary ability bonus (starting with +3 at level 1, and using ASIs to increase it at level 4 and 8) and the resulting spell casting DC. 60% is based on monsters up to CR 10; for all monsters up to CR20 it would be 62%, but over 90% of play happens in the low and mid tier levels.

I don't think I quite follow your last paragraph about perceivable effects, the spell describes a "beam of crackling energy". How would the relative damage change be if they had Agonizing Blast? The Charisma bonus isn't affected by crits.

@TREB Yes, you can see the spell, but can you see if it does damage?

If you’re going to base the whole answer on stats about average hit and save rates, you need to cite where you got the numbers from. I know where you got it from, but to someone who doesn’t, it looks like you’re just making stuff up, because those stats are not common knowledge.

@ThomasMarkov I added a description on how I arrived at those stats.

Re: "players like rolling", I think it was an official variant in 4e where every roll was done by the players. When they attacked, they rolled d20 + hit as normal, and when monsters attacked, the player targeted rolled d20 + defence - 10

@NobodytheHobgoblin If the enemy was damaged the player would be asked to roll for damage, so the player can always tell for any damaging effect, weapons too. In this specific case the DM should describe a failed save as the beam of energy hitting them and a successful save as them dodging it. Vary the description based on resistance, immunity or vulnerability.

@TREB As a DM, usually I let roll the damage regardless the ST is successfull or not, for avoiding metagaming.

@TREB You are right, if the DM does not ask them to roll, this would give it away. Anyways, this is a very minor downside, and up a lot to how the DM in each case handles it.

The rules say that the Player rolls for damage when damage is inflicted, for weapon attacks and damaging spells. It's quite a change on top of a change that players are asked to roll for damage that isn't being applied.

@TREB I just removed that paragraph, as I think it is really minor, and maybe less is more for the question here.

@TREB "It's quite a change on top of a change that players are asked to roll for damage that isn't being applied" it's not really. I prefer not spending my time rolling, so as player I'd often roll attack + damage at the same time. This avoids the cumbersome roll to attack -> see if you succeeded -> roll for damage which takes more time. If there is a save, I'd also just roll the damage as the GM rolls, to save time. If nothing happens, my roll didn't take time anyway, since the GM had to do theirs. In Roll20 I even do macros for these.

@VLAZ that simply does not address the concerns of this player, the problem is not time, it's that they now have to avoid mixing up d10 and d20 dice, they have to know which number to add to which and they don't want to have to be constantly reminded. You're offering a time-saving measure when that's just not what this question is about.

@TREB I'm offering my perspective. You claimed the approach is radically different for players. I'm saying it's not. And in my experience, it's really not an uncommon for players to roll for damage without that being applied. At no point did I suggest you need to deal with the time aspect of rolling. I said that it was me who doesn't like wasting time, hence why I practice this. I thought giving a concrete reason would suffice to justify that it's not an unjustified or random practice.

@TREB If the player doesn't like being reminded can they not write it down and remind themselves? You are constantly defensive against people trying to be helpful because you haven't given a clear explanation on your real issue here.

No.  Ranged attacks are not meaningfully more complex than forcing saving throws.  Any problems the player is having can be addressed through narration, such as a quick narrative description at the top of the player's turn about what threats are being faced.  If the player is right next to an enemy, for instance, describe the particular enemy as baring down on the player's character, looking for an opening to strike.  This translates the rule problem to a common sense problem, which most players will pick up on quickly.
Don't fix something until you've actually encountered a problem.
You don't cite any actual examples of how Eldritch Blast has tripped up players, you're just assuming that it will.  So why try to fix it?  What if this hypothetical player is actually completely fine with the rules as written?  Why jump to the assumption that the system is broken?
In reality, all this does is teach the player that the rules in the book can't be trusted.  If you're trying to teach someone how to play, the quickest way to shoot yourself in the foot is by giving them contradicting sources.  This most often take the form of a meek player being taught by multiple overbearing players with different teaching methods, but contradicting the book (without a really good and consistent reason!) also very much counts.
And, for the love of all that's good and holy,
Please do not risk insulting your player's competence.
I've personally never been on the receiving end of this kind of thing, but my wife frequently has.  Being both a woman and dyslexic, she has had a lot of people (including me at times!) try to dumb things down for her, especially when it comes to games.  While it's always done from a place of good intentions, it really pisses her off.
When I finally got the message through my own thick skull, I just sat her down with a rulebook, told her the page numbers relevant to her character, and gave her a few hours to read it at her own pace.  In that time, she figured out a way to color-code her character sheet in a way that made sense to her and most of the problems went away.
Moral of the story, I suppose, is that unless you are actually seeing a problem at your table, implementing this kind of fix preemptively is wrong-headed and will almost certainly come across as condescending.

Ask them if they want that change
Like explained in other answer this spell is obviously weaker than it's normal counterpart. But to me the main problem looks like you just assuming that your player don't want to learn. If you are trying to DM for them that single session and don't play again any time soon then the power level of the spell don't really matter. Your question suggest that you plan to for your player to learn the rules and have fun at the table, soon that person will learn those rules you presented to them and hopefully will try their best to apply them, but then you tell them u made up special rules for them or they go to different table and play the same thing while getting confronted about strange spell they imply is real.
Whatever might be the case in your situation you should definitely ask them if they want to play by those simplified rules and if they do explain to them what homebrew rules are.

Of course I'd tell them and give them a choice, it goes without saying the DM clears homebrew with ALL players. No exception. They want to learn in the game, they don't want to do "homework" for games night. I hope you actually corroborate that it's weaker for yourself, and aren't just assuming it is correct. Because if the enemies are Hobgoblins, it's 40% chance for a spell attack to hit but 55% chance to fail a Dex save vs spell DC. It's it's a Gnoll, equal chance. These rules aren't simplified, they're different, perhaps more suited to them, spell saves are common outside of cantrips.

How is this answering the question about Eldritch Blast? This is an unrelated point that you shouldn't deceive new players about homebrew, that's not specific to this question.

The player needs a buddy, not a rules change
This looks like a classic 'X Y' problem to me. You have a player that doesn't want to learn the rules before coming to game, and you've decided that it's better to change the rules for them instead of helping them.
Almost all of the new players that I've DM'd for didn't do an ounce of D&D reading outside of game. They still learned the rules just fine at the table. It took time, a lot more time than I would have liked, but they got there. If your player is struggling with ranged attacks then they are also going to struggle with Wisdom (perception) checks and Dexterity (stealth) checks, and I don't see you suggesting to change those too.
Pair your new player up with an experienced player. Have them sit next to each other (if applicable). It's the buddy's job to point out the right dice, naming them and describing when you'd use them, to point out the right numbers and help make sure the math is right. Make sure that the support carries over to in-character, too.
If no other player can/will be the buddy, then its your job as the DM. Stay calm. Be patient. Repeat the rules simply and clearly as many times as needed. I've been a year into a campaign and still reminding a rogue that they get sneak dice in certain situations, but they get it eventually and you're not helping your players by changing the rules instead of teaching them.

You're the second person I've seen use the "X Y Problem", could you add a note what it means? They aren't going to struggle with ability checks as I use "Skills with Different Abilities" rule (PHB pg171) so everyone has to negotiate what ability mod or proficiency to add. Also the DM calls when to roll. Not the player. So everyone is on a level playing field with "when do I roll" and "what do I add". Different from combat where the players know what to do and precisely when to roll and what to add without prompt.

@TREB https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Attack rolls aren't different than skill checks. The player says 'I want to hit that guy with EB' and you say 'Ok, roll a d20 and add the number you have written down next to Eldritch Blast on your sheet.' Or you can say 'Actually, that guy's out of range' or 'that pillar is in the way' if that's the case, but that's the same kind of thing you'd be saying if they want to make friends with the squirrel or are trying to pick someone's pocket. Attack rolls are just so common that most players are anticipating those responses and factoring them into tactics. A good buddy will help introduce that.

The distinction is the "problem" is the issue of the novice player amongst experienced players is an almost all-encompassing topic, it affects almost all aspects of 5th edition. To ask that question is just too broad and I have already answered this question except for this one matter of homebrew a change to Eldritch Blast. Also, it matters that the DM doesn't change what ability or proficiency applies to an attack roll, that IS different, that changes the interaction.

don't take this as snide, but I think you should instead ask the question of "how to deal with a novice player" because clearly that is a question that interests you more than answering my question about this proposed rules change to EB to serve a particular purpose. I am not being snarky, I'm serious, you've got a good question there.
